# How to add multiple elements in the python input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
x1 = 1
x2 = 2
ans=int(input(x1, "+", x2, "="))

if (ans==(x1+x2)):
   print("Correct")
else:
   print("Incorrect")
```

I have this code which is supposed to tell the user to input a value for what they think is the correct answer  for x1 + x2 , however when I run the code, the input part is giving me an error. Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: `ans=int(input('{} + {} ='.format(x1, x2)))`

Comment: Or: `int(input(f'{x1} + {x2} = '))`.

Comment: What error are you getting? Please [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Input takes only 1 parameter. By using comma, you are passing 4. So, just convert them into a single string by using '+' operator instead of ','.

```
x1 = 1
x2 = 2

ans = int(input(str(x1) + "+" + str(x2) + "="))
# As string concatenation is an expensive operation, the following
# might be an optimal approach for acheiving the same result. 

ans = int(input("".join(str(x1), "+", str(x2), "=")))
# But in this scenario, it doesn't matter because the number of strings 
# being concatenated and the length of them are both small. So, it won't 
# make much difference. 

# Also now, Python3.5+ supports `f-strings`. So, you can do something like
ans = int(input(f"{x1} + {x2} = "))

if (ans == (x1 + x2)):
   print("Correct")
else:
   print("Incorrect")
```

Comment: How is a coma important here?

Comment: `+` is not the recommended way to build a string.

Comment: Agreed! Updated the answer with other (more optimized) approaches as well.

Answer (score 0):

## Answer:

Replace

```
ans=int(input(x1, "+", x2, "="))
```

with

```
ans = int(input("".join(map(str, [x1, "+", x2, "="]))))
```

## Reference:

1. [input](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input)
2. [str](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str)
3. [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)
4. [str.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)

Comment: This maybe a GREAT answer.  But why not explain WHY?

Answer (score 0):

Replace with this

if(ans==(input("Enter x1")+input("Enter x2"))):